# How can i change the font color of a variable in PHP inside echo

Tags: php

```
echo  $display;
```

so we know the default color is black. But i want to change it to white. Tried codes such as

```
"<div style=\"color: white;\">$display</div>";
```

but it doesn't work. Can you help me with this guys? thanks in advance.

Comment: You would still need `echo` in front of that string. Unless you have CSS which is overriding it with `!important`, that should work.  `echo "<div style='color: white;'>$display</div>";`

Comment: Better to add a class though, and use your CSS to style the class. `echo "<div class='someClass'>$display</div>";`

Comment: Colour has nothing to do with PHP. PHP creates HTML, the HTML is sent to the browser, the browser works out what colours you want. Start with just HTML and hard-coded text, get the colours right, then add PHP variables.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
    $Color = "red";
    $Text = "This text is red";

    echo '<div style="Color:'.$Color.'">'.$Text.'</div>';
?>
```

In php, you can use `.` to add variables together. In this case, the final output of the echo line is:

```
<div style="Color:red">This text is red</div>
```

An example of this code in use can be seen [here](http://beta.tinyclark.com/stackstuff/textcolor.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
<span style="color:white;"><?php echo $display; ?></span>
```

Hope it might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$yourtext = "Some text";
?>
<div style="color:<?php echo ((@$_GET["color"]) && !empty(@$_GET["color"])) ? $_GET["color"] : "black"; ?>" ><?php echo $yourtext; ?></div>
```

In Url `http://yoursite.you/yourpage.php?color=white`

Green

Yellow

Blue
etc...

Answer (score 0):

If applied color doesn't work even inline-style, so you can use `!important` word, cos maybe all div colors come from css file and suppress inline-styles.

```
"<div style=\"color: white !important;\">$display</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a div and you want to change its text and color of text, then simply copy and paste this code it will work for you.

```
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
      echo"var ele= document.getElementById('login_status');
     ele.innerHTML ='* Your <font color=#ff3322> Email </font> is incorrect ';";

   echo "</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I write the answer in case someone has the same question and does not know where to look. I think you wanted to print links so this is why the previous methods didn't work.Inside your php file write the following:

```
echo "<html>
<head>
     <style>
     /* unvisited link */
     a:link {
        color: red;
     }

     /* visited link */
     a:visited {
         color: green;
     }

     /* mouse over link */
      a:hover {
          color: hotpink;
     }

     /* selected link */
     a:active {
         color: blue;
     }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    $variableYouWantToChangeColor
</body>
</html>";
```

You can change/remove parts of the css so it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

its usable with bootstrap

```
 <p class="text-primary"><?php echo $distance; ?></p>
```

i found that when i try echo result from a calculation

```
 <p class="text-primary"><?php echo  round ($distance,2); ?></p>
```